# Make clip reference (link to) different media file(s) in Premiere

Tags: premiere

After editing a Premiere project and seeing a final video, I often want to change the underlying media, whether that means processing the audio file differently or re-rendering some frames of an animation.

So far, I've been achieving this effect by appending '_old' to the names of the old media files and then saving new versions with the name I used when importing to Premiere, so Premiere will be oblivious to the difference. To be safe and organized, though, I want to do this without the renaming trickery.

Searching so far, I've only been able to find solutions for relinking missing or moved media. I can't seem to figure out how to link to different media. If I could just break the link between a clip and media without deleting/moving the media, that would be good enough, since I could just break the link and then pick the new file when repairing the link. (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click, set Media Offline

Right click again, Relink Media

Select your new clip.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused and thought "make offline" meant to internalize the data into to project file so it didn't need a reference, similar to what offline operation means in various other apps/services. Will upvote once I have the reputation. Can you can offer any insight into why this is called "offline" rather than unlinking?

Comment: I guess this is just the way Adobe named their UI, I admit though that it can be confusing as you mentioned.